# Lambda Calculus -- function expressed using Mocking Bird seems like it should be recursive but is not

Tags: javascript, python, recursion, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

Using JavaScript. Lets defined the following:

```
M = f => f(f)  // Mocking Bird
I = a => a  // Identity
```

Suppose now we write this expression

```
M( f => M( x => f) )
```

This would seem to be recursive and hit the maximum callstack. Let us expand this once

```
( f => M( x => f) )  (f => M( x => f) )
```

We see that we can keep going

```
(f => (x => f)( x => f))(f => (x => f)( x => f))

(x => (f => (x => f)( x => f)))(x => (f => (x => f)( x => f)))
```

... and so on. But in the browser or node, this isn't recursive. It is a function that behaves like `Identity`

```
I('foobar')
// returns 'foobar'

M( f => M( x => f) )('foobar')
// returns 'foobar'

(x => (f => (x => f)( x => f)))(x => (f => (x => f)( x => f))) ('foobar')
// returns 'foobar'
```

Please explain why the function doesn't keep calling itself until hitting the maximum callstack but instead returns a function that behaves like `Identity`

This same phenomenon can be expressed using Python

```
M = lambda f: f(f)
I = lambda a: a

M( lambda f: M(lambda x: f)) ('foobar')
# returns 'foobar'

I('foobar')
# returns 'foobar'
```

---

## Update

Starting with

```
M( f => M( x => f) )
```

If we write out the inner `M( x => f)`

```
M( f => ( x=> f )(x => f) )
```

We see that it doesn't matter what is passed into `(x => f)(x => f)`, the `x` is ignored and returns just `f`

```
M( f => f )
```

Which is simply

```
f => f
```

Comment: The decisive point is `x` in `M( x => f)`, which remains completely unused. As a result `f` in `M( f => M( x => f) )` evaluates to `f => M( x => f)` and when this partially applied function is finally applied to `foobar`, `f` becomes `foobar` and is simply returned, since `x` is ignored.

Comment: It is interesting because `M( f => M(f))` is recursive and immediately hits the callstack

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've updated the question to reflect my understanding now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 M(/*a*/ f => M( /*b*/ x => f) )('foobar')
```

*a* is called with *f = a* :

```
M(/*b*/ x => *a*)
```

*b* is called with x being b it returns a :

```
/*a*/ f => M(/*b*/ x => f)
```

which is called with "foobar", so f is " foobar":

```
M(/*b*/ x => "foobar")
```

" foobar" is returned

---

Basically it works because:

```
M( x => f)
```

Always returns *f*, so the whole thing is equal to

```
M( f => f )
```

Which then does:

```
(f => f)(f => f)
```

which is

```
f => f
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll update my question to also reflect my understand.